# Yarn service parameter for pseudodistributed

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop

I'm trying to set up Hadoop in the pseudodistributed form. So I edited the suggested xml files. In the file `yarn-site.xml`, I had to insert:

```
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
```

What is the "mapreduce_shuffle" option?

Answer (score 1):

The `mapreduce_shuffle` in this config file is part of [Plugable Shuffle and Sort](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/PluggableShuffleAndPluggableSort.html).  Shuffle and Sort are what connect the mappers to the reducers. A nice graphical representation of this is the following (shuffle is called "copy" in this figure):

[image: Pipeline]

The Hadoop arcitecture alllows these steps to be customized:

> The pluggable shuffle and pluggable sort capabilities allow replacing the built in shuffle and sort logic with alternate implementations. Example use cases for this are: using a different application protocol other than HTTP such as RDMA for shuffling data from the Map nodes to the Reducer nodes; or replacing the sort logic with custom algorithms that enable Hash aggregation and Limit-N query.

The `mapreduce_shuffle` parameter is mentioned in the [Hadoop Docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/PluggableShuffleAndPluggableSort.html#NodeManager_Configuration_properties.2C_yarn-site.xml_in_all_nodes:), and is the default value for this configuration.